# PHP Multiple divide string with php

Tags: php, string, divide

I have little problem with this, I am total beginer and I need help, how to divide string with php. I have this code and works fine only if I have one separator in string, but I need full control what is divided and how. This is little modified code from yootheme warp modules.php. I have 3 separators in string '`||`' or '`#|`' or "`|#`", which may be in string or not. `$title` is `$module->title` from joomla module title name. Our string. `$split_color` and `$subtitle` I control on/off for different styles for modules.

```
$title          = $module->title;
$split_color    = 1;
$subtitle       = 1;
// split title in two colors
if ($split_color) {
    $pos = mb_strpos($title, '#|');
    if ($pos !== false) {
        $title = '<span class="color">'.mb_substr($title, 0, $pos).'</span>'.'<span class="no-color">'.mb_substr($title, $pos + 2).'</span>';
    }
}

if ($split_color) {
    $pos = mb_strpos($title, '|#');
    if ($pos !== false) {
        $title = '<span class="no-color">'.mb_substr($title, 0, $pos).'</span>'.'<span class="color">'.mb_substr($title, $pos + 2).'</span>';
    }
}

// create subtitle
if ($subtitle) {
    $pos = mb_strpos($title, '||');
    if ($pos !== false) {
        $title = '<span class="title">'.mb_substr($title, 0, $pos).'</span>'.'<span class="subtitle">'.mb_substr($title, $pos + 2).'</span>';
    }
}
```

String is simple plain text name which can be divided with separators For Example:

`Text 1 |# Text 2 || Text 3 #| Text 4`

and my problem is how to do that to work all together.

'`||`' - divide string on two parts, left part must be in `<span class="title"></span>`, right part must be in `<span class="title"></span>`. For example:

String 1: `Text 1 Text 2 || Text 3 Text 4`

Result 1:

```
<span class="title">Text 1 Text 2</span>
<span class="subtitle">Text3 Text4</span>
```

'`#|`' - divide string on two parts, left part is placed into between `<span class="color"></span>` and right part in to `<span class="no-color"></span>`. For example:

String 2: `Text 1 Text 2 #| Text 3 Text 4`

Result 2:

```
<span class="color">Text 1 Text 2</span>
<span class="no-color">Text3 Text4</span>
```

'`|#`' - divide string on two parts, left part is placed into between `<span class="no-color"></span>` and right part in to `<span class="color"></span>`. For example:

String 2: `Text 1 Text 2 |# Text 3 Text 4`

Result 2:

```
<span class="no-color">Text 1 Text 2</span>
<span class="color">Text3 Text4</span>
```

But can be used all separator on one time.

String 3: `Text 1 #|Text 2 || Text 3 |# Text 4`

Result 3:

```
<span class="title">    
  <span class="color">Text 1</span>
  <span class="no-color">Text2</span>
</span>
<span class="subtitle">
  <span class="no-color">Text 3</span>
  <span class="color">Text4</span>
</span>
```

All possible strings Examples:

String a: `Text 1 Text 2 Text 3 Text 4`

String b: `Text 1 Text 2 || Text 3 Text 4`

String c: `Text 1 Text 2 #| Text 3 Text 4`

String d: `Text 1 Text 2 |# Text 3 Text 4`

String e: `Text 1 #|Text 2 || Text 3 Text 4`

String f: `Text 1 Text 2 || Text 3 |# Text 4`

String g: `Text 1 |#Text 2 || Text 3 Text 4`

String h: `Text 1 Text 2 || Text 3 #| Text 4`

String i: `Text 1 #| Text 2 || Text 3 #| Text 4`

String j: `Text 1 |# Text 2 || Text 3 |# Text 4`

String k: `Text 1 #| Text 2 || Text 3 |# Text 4`

String l: `Text 1 |# Text 2 || Text 3 #| Text 4`

One more thing me occured when I wrote, I can't use two '`#|`' or '`#|`' separator without '`||`' in string, or would not better use sperators '`|#`' and '`#|`'to control what is betwwen this separator is in `<span class="color"></span>` and what is outside is in `<span class="no-color"></span>`.  Something like this.

String: `|#Text 1 #| Text |# 2 #| || Text 3 |# Text 4 #|`
Result:

```
<span class="title">    
  <span class="color">Text 1</span>
  <span class="no-color">Text</span>
  <span class="color">2</span>
</span>
<span class="subtitle">
  <span class="no-color">Text 3</span>
  <span class="color">Text4</span>
</span>
```

I think it will be better, but one thing is how you want to do and second thing is how it write in php. Thank you everyone who want help me. Very appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding correctly, then this should work:

```
$parts  = explode(' || ', $title);

//title ... 
$output = '<span class="title">';
$pos    = mb_strpos($parts[0], '#|');
if($pos !== false){
    $output .= '<span class="color">'.mb_substr($parts[0], 0, $pos).'</span><span class="no-color">'.mb_substr($parts[0], $pos + 2).'</span>'; 
} else {
    $output .= $parts[0];
}
$output .= "</span>\n";

if(isset($parts[1])){
    //subtitle ... 
    $output .= '<span class="subtitle">';
    $pos     = mb_strpos($parts[1], '|#');
    if ($pos !== false) {
        $output .= '<span class="no-color">'.mb_substr($parts[1], 0, $pos).'</span><span class="color">'.mb_substr($parts[1], $pos + 2).'</span>';
    } else {
        $output .= $parts[1];
    }
    $output .= "</span>\n";
}

echo $output;
```

Answer (score 0):

Haven't tested it, but give this a shot:

```
function get_inner_spans($content) {
    #this function will handle "title" content or "subtitle" content

    #determine if we need to split this content string - we may not need to
    if (mb_strpos($content, '#|')) {
        $delimeter = '#|';
    } elseif (mb_strpos($content, '|#')) {
        $delimiter = '|#';
    }

    if (isset($delimiter)) {
        list($color, $no_color) = explode($delimiter, $content);

        $inner_html = '<span class="color">' . $color . '</span>';
        $inner_html .= '<span class="no-color">' . $no_color . '</span>';
    } else {
        #no need to split this string, so just return the original string passed
        $inner_html = $content;
    }

    return $inner_html;
}

#i'm assuming this string will always contain '||'
$input = 'Text 1 Text 2 Text 3 #| Text 4 || Text 5 |# Text 6';

list($title_content, $subtitle_content) = explode('||', $input);

$output_html = '<span class="title">'
             . get_inner_spans($title_content)
             . '</span>'
             . '<span class="subtitle">'
             . get_inner_spans($subtitle_content)
             . '</span>';

echo $output_html;
```

It's my understanding that both the title and subtitle parts of the string could contain *either* `#|` or `|#`. The `get_spans` function I wrote will match on either one. Hopefully the rest of the logic is pretty clear.

I find it helps to give variables very clear names that describe exactly what they contain. Makes things easier on yourself.